# Is it good practice to use the same variable for different things inside a function

Tags: python, variables, coding-style

In a function like the following:

```
def foo(case):
    if case == 1:
        my_var = []
        # then do something with my_var
    elif case == 2:
        my_var = {}
        # then do something with my_var
```

Since the variable `my_var` lives in different cases, so it shouldn't cause a problem at runtime. But is this a good practice in Python?

Comment: Why not use `my_list = []` and `my_dict = {}` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be confusing for other people who work on the same code. Several style guides also discourage reusing the same variable name for different purposes. If you can avoid it then you should, although there can also be good reasons to deviate from this rule. Are they really the same thing? One is a list of items, the other is a dictionary of values so what do they contain? If you can think of a more descriptive variable name then that's a good idea.

Comment: The example I gave is a bit contrived. The actual situation I am facing involves a list vs. a tuple. Semantically, they store the same sort of data. But functionally, the tuple will be hashed as a key in a dictionary for recording purposes, while the list may be updated so it is handy to have adding and removing functionalities.

Comment: Can't you convert the list to a tuple when you need the key? That would leave you with only one situation.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no.  When a variable means more than one thing, it adds potential confusion.  Plus, if you ever have to refactor your code to add new features or something, you have a good chance of having made that task more difficult.  That said, Python is a duck typed language, so if it is functionally the same thing but the data type is different, you are probably good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Apply your own judgement.  If you feel that the meaning of the object is similar in both cases, using the same name might improve readability.  If you feel that using the same name for different things is confusing, don't do it.

Comment: but only if the different things behaves the same (duck typing)

Answer (score 2):

I would say no, because then you have a greater chance of getting unexpected results and annoying debugging.  But sometimes there could be a specific reason where this is a good idea. So it really depends on what you're doing.